# spring boot microservices maven architecture

Tags: spring, maven, microservices, devops

I am currently building a spring boot application with a micro-service architecture.
I am looking for clean ways to reuse code.

My idea is to pull out common code in a shared module.
(e.g. base classes which model classes in microservices inherit from, interfaces which are reused in any mvc controller, domain code which is the same for each bound context).
Concrete implementations and service-only model classes etc. are on the submodule (microservice) level.

I am building stuff with maven and also managing dependencies. My question is about how to structure maven modules and dependencies in such a setup.

Where do shared libraries go? How and when are they built and referenced via dependency?
Is it good to use a BOM for managing dependencies and only override specific versions in microservices when needed?
How is the bom included? How and when is it built?

I can think about one way to handle it which I don't really like:

1. Have a (super-parent) maven pom which handles dependency management and can be included in submodules (micro-services) with import scope. (BOM)
2. microservices poms build all their dependencies (including BOM and shared module)

Problems:

when declaring submodules for building dependencies the pom must be of type pom aswell, so for every microservice module I would also need a parent pom aswell

If the super-parent or BOM includes a module section which declares all submodules (microservices) I cannot build it from the ms-level, since there would be circular dependencies.

Why would I even declare submodules in the bom? because in some IDEs like Intellij the maven plugin/support includes the submodules in the structure overview.

Can you please point me to some good advice for handling maven architecture for microservices in a solid and clean way? (less code/configuration duplication as possible, performant build etc.)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing you should concern about with the microservices architecture is the isolation of the services from each other. That implies that you should share as little as possible.

As I tried different approaches over past 6-7 years I can confidently say

- Don't ever use a parent pom for different microservices. Each microservice can use different version of the same libraries depending our their own needs. Having parent pom may sound convenient initially but it creates significant issues in the long run for isolation.
- Don't ever try to focus on code reuse between the microservices. That doesn't mean that you can't use utility libraries etc. But sharing model classes etc. will bind the microservices to each other which will damage the freedom/isolation substantially. Instead you should rely on proper contract between the microservices.

I see that your approach are mostly for implementation convenience but there are other things you should concern more over time like deployment/release, maintenance, testing of the components which could be harmed by lack of proper isolation.

Comment: I understand that sharing model classes (or base classes) and inheritance implies coupling. The main issue I have right now, is that I need to share some parts between them e.g. Interfaces for business logic that is reused in any mvc component etc.

So for this "utility library" as you called it... how can I manage this dependency in a microservice maven multimodule setup? Do I have to build that artifact completely isolated and push it to e.g. artifactory or is it reliable to build it as a dependency of each needed microservice?

Comment: What do you mean by "business logic reuse"? When I mention about utility library I meant to have some specific utility functions which doesn't contains any business related stuff only for very generic problems. If you also meant that then the approach you proposed is fine. If you are talking about a library contains business related stuff as a contract between different microservices then I would say this would cause several issues. The right way to share the business logic in microservices is not sharing it at all and let the responsible microservice handle it and provide you the result.

Comment: Yes I meant generic stuff used in the business logic. Sorry for the confusion. 
How would you handle the build and dependency management of such a library with maven? Should I completely extract it as a standalone project? The build and deployment process would require more overhead. In the short-run I would like to avoid this.

Comment: Yes you should have it as a separate library like in apache-commons libraries. But from your question I still feel like you want to change the version of the dependency of this library in two different microservices simultaneously and release them? Is this your plan?

Comment: the dependency on this library must not necessarily be the same version, but if I could avoid a seperate manual build step I would prefer that, so that it would be compiled on service compile time

I do not want to pull in any tools like artifactory, since they consume time to setup, need some further knowledge etc.